# Sort a dictionary/list by value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm creating a game and I'd like to print out the user scores from highest to lowest.

This is my code so far

```
player_scores = {}
for line in reversed(open("playerscores.txt").readlines()):
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' / ')
    score = int(score)
    if name in player_scores and len(player_scores[name]) < 3:
        player_scores[name].append(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        player_scores[name] = list((score,))
```

Names in playerscores.txt are stored like:

```
Bob / 10
Jill / 10
```

My code takes the last 3 scores from the user(last 3 lives) and uses that as the base. I need print the users names along with the highest scores to the lowest.

The solutions at [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value/7237524#7237524) do not work. I end up getting outputs such as:

```
[('Alex', [1]), ('Joeseph', [32, 576]), ('Steve', [33]), ('Bob', [55, 22])]
```

which are not sorted.

Comment: could you provide the playersscores.txt example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes this is a duplicate. Sui21245 go to the link and look at Roberto Bonvallet answer of `from operator import itemgetter
sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))`

Comment: If you apply the solution you linked to with that dictionary instead:
`maxs = { (k, max(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems()}`, is it what you want ?

Comment: Top score would be 576. I'm getting AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' for most of these solutions.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. It may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The difference from your case to the answer being pointed as a duplicate is that in thsicase you can compare just with the value of each key, as it is a list. You have to compare (I suppose) with the maximum score in that list - so the keyfunction has to take care of that:

```
score_list = sorted(player_scores.items(), key=lambda item: max(item[1]))
```

Comment: This still returns a list of playernames and _all_ scores, whereas OP seems to want a list of just the names and top score, so either you have to map the entire dict to just the max values before sorting, or do the same with the result (effectively calling `max` twice for each item).

Answer (score 0):

First, get the top scores for each player from the list of all scores:

```
>>> player_scores = dict([('Alex', [1]), ('Joeseph', [32, 576]), ('Steve', [33]), ('Bob', [55, 22])])
>>> top_scores = {name: max(scores) for name, scores in player_scores.items()}
```

Now you can use `operator.itemgetter` to sort by value. Remember to reverse the result!

```
>>> sorted(top_scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('Joeseph', 576), ('Bob', 55), ('Steve', 33), ('Alex', 1)]
```

Finally, to print it, just do something like

```
for name, score in your_sorted_scores_list:
    print("{:20} - {}".format(name, score))
```

Comment: I don't think using "itemgetter" here simplifies anything. (actually, as we can see, neithr in the simliar answer - its uneeded usage obscured the actual usage of the "key" parameter for people who don't already understand it)

Comment: (And I think it is needles to point out you are iteratign twice over the scores  items, and having to deal with an intermediary result when there is no need for it at all)

Comment: @jsbueno I've always had the impression that `itemgetter` is considered more 'pythonic' than using a lambda. Also, I think there's no way around the intermediary result, since OP wants the values to be the top score, so you have to transform the list, either before or after sorting. Either that way, or do `max` again when printing the result.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Python 2*
This is one way to do it:
**EDITED**

```
player_scores = {
    'Bob': 12,
    'Pete': 3,
    'Jim': 10,
    'Joe': 15,
    'Bill': 14,
    'Sam': 2,
    'Tim': 10
}

k = sorted(player_scores, key=player_scores.__getitem__, reverse=True)
v = sorted(player_scores.values(), reverse=True)
sorted_player_scores = zip(k,v)
print sorted_player_scores
```

Output:

```
[('Joe', 15), ('Bill', 14), ('Bob', 12), ('Jim', 10), ('Tim', 10), ('Pete', 3), ('Sam', 2)]
```

Comment: This has quadratic complexity! Also, this will not work if two players have the same score.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for you comment, I edited my answer accordingly. I appreciate it!